# How can I compile simpleScalar in cygwin using alpha configuration?

Tags: linux, windows-7, cygwin, cpu-architecture

I need to install simplescalar on windows 7. For that reason, I installed cygwin. I need to use simplescalar because I need to do a lab about Benchmarks.

I already installed  SimpleScalar on Debian and I compiled it using the alpha configuration without any problem. However, when I try to do the same on windows using cygwin, I'm having issues.

I am trying to compile simplescalar using alpha configuration. since I'm using windows 7, cygwin and I used the following steps:

```
make config-alpha
make
```

When I run the make command to compile the simulator, it shows me a lot of errors.

```
syscall.c: 805:25: error: 'TCP_NODELAY' undeclared here (not in a function); did you mean 'O_NDEALY'?
804  { OSF_TCP_NODELAY,  TCP_NODELAY},
O_NDEALY

syscall.c: 805:25: error: 'TCP_MAXSEG' undeclared here (not in a function); did you mean 'TMP_MAX'?
804  { OSF_TCP_MAXSEG,  TCP_MAXSEG},
TMP_MAX

syscall.c:2636:56  error: invalid use of undefined type 'struct dirent' i++, cnt < regs -> regs_R[MD_REG_V0] && p->d_reclen > 0;

syscall.c:2637:35 error: invalid use of undefined type 'struct dirent' i++, cnt = p->d_reclen, p=(struct dirent *)(buf+cn 2637)
```

However, if I use pisa configuration, I can compile the simulator without any problem.

Is there any additional steps I need to do or any additional packages I need to download in cygwin in order to compile simplescala using alpha configuration?

Some of the packages that I have downloaded to do my lab in cygwin have been wget, nano and devel.

Comment: Probably the code doesn't include all the headers it should, and accidentally relied on Linux headers including other Linux headers.  But apparently cygwin doesn't do that, so look up where those symbols are defined (google for docs, or grep the headers).

Comment: But did your Cygwin GCC really said `did you mean 'O_NDEALY'`?  That itself is a typo for `O_NDELAY` from `fcntl.h` (which presumably the code is including, so the compiler sees that name and guesses as a fuzzy match as a hint; in this case it's *not* the symbol you're looking for.) If your cygwin really printed that, your cygwin install is broken.  But I'm guessing you somehow corrupted the compiler output further when copy/pasting it into your stack-overflow question from a terminal window.

Comment: TCP_NODELAY is defined in netinet/tcp.h